# How to label customers in data

Tags: machine-learning, encoding

I am trying to use Neural Networks for fraud detection, question is how can i label users column (about 1 million users) so that each user is having unique behavior depends on their transaction/browsing parameters. most of my columns are nominal columns

Upon reading i got to know for sure not one-hot encoding, i should go for combination of target and leave one out encoding. is that right ? can you people guide me in right direction.

Same encoding can be used for new users/customers who are not there in training data ?

Answer (score 0):

I would train the network differently depending on the data.

- If fraud and normal examples are there for each user then I'd train the network on each user's data independently and store their weights, to be retrieved once they perform an action so it's vetted.  And for new users I'd train the network on the entire dataset for all 1 million users and whenever a new user shows up I'd use those user agnostic weights for them. For customisation I'd either start a new row for their data in the training set and eventually retrain the network for their usage or online learning so the model can learn over time.
- If the users do not have individualised fraud/genuine counter examples I'd use a one Vs rest strategy where the user data is true behaviour and that of others as fraud. Then I'd store the weights and retrieve them at inference time.

Comment: Hi, do you have any blog/examples to go through what you have explained, so that i can understand better.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. But you could share your data so I have a look at it and show you a working example

Comment: Hey how can i add my sample dataset ? all upload sites are block in my org..

Comment: Maybe Puch to a GitHub repo or use a cloud service provider

Answer (score 0):

Hey i got the best way how i want to label the data(strings/categorical) to retain the behaviour for each customer.

I can use catboost or python library Crypto.Util.number to convert any string in to unique number later upon normalize the data.

Thanks.